# How can I solve the TISE for a particle confined to a curve that isn't simple?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I solved the TISE for different simple closed curves (e.g square, circle) as an exercise in finding and applying the correct boundary conditions but realised I don't know how to do it when the curve can't be continuously mapped onto an interval.

For example, what are the boundary conditions if a particle is confined to a square and its diagonal? (see picture)
[image: square and its diagonal]
I'm assuming the hamiltonian is of the form p^2/2m

Thank you :)

Comment: One possible approach would be to solve the TISE on the upper right triangle alone;  and then by symmetry a solution for the lower left would be the reflection of the solution for the upper right (though you'd probably have to renormalize things appropriately.)  But it's not clear to me that you could generate all possible solutions this way, and this approach wouldn't work at all for a graph without this kind of symmetry.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense